# Discordpy como pegar o nome e não a referencia ao objeto

Tags: python

Estou brincando um pouco com a biblioteca Discord no python, mas cheguei num problema.

Quando quero pegar o nome do usuário que mandou a mensagem, e o id e creio que tudo que faça referência aos dados do usuário o formato que volta é como se estivesse usando **repr** e não print.

Esse é o código que tenho

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
    
intents = discord.Intents.default()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='dia-', description=description, intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-')

@bot.command()  
async def info(ctx, user = discord.Member):  
    await ctx.send(f'{user.mention}\'s id: `{user.id}`') 

bot.run('token')
```

Quando vou para o discord e uso o prefixo "dia-" e coloco o commando "info" (dia-info) essa é a saída que tenho no discord

```
<property object at 0x000001C8E4F2ACC0>'s id: <property object at 0x000001C8E4F342C0>
```

Gostaria que aparecesse o meu nome e id no discord, mas não faço ideia de como proceder!

Comment: O método a ser chamado não é `owner_id`? É o que parece dando uma olhada rápida na documentação: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot

Comment: Nesse caso vai chamar o criador do bot, o que eu quero é o que vai pegar o id do usuário que mandou a mensagem. Creio que ainda que fosse esse o caso, o problema não está no id em si, mas na forma que ele aparece como "<property object at 0x000001C8E4F342C0>". Mas valeu por tirar um tempo pra até olhar na doc mano!

Comment: é que "<property object at 0x000001C8E4F342C0>" é o local que o objeto está na memória. Isso acontece quando o método `__repr__` não está definido para o objeto. Então acho que você deve procurar a informação que vc deseja em outro método do objeto. Passe um dir no objeto e veja se tem algum método que pode ter a informação que você quer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@bot.command()  
async def info(ctx):  
    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.name}`') 

bot.run('token')
```

Dessa forma pega apenas o nome, se tirar a parte "name" deixando só o "author" vem o nome é o #id, se colocar invés de "name", "id" pega o id (sem ser o #id), dessa forma resolvi meu problema!

Comment: [Não use cumprimentos e agradecimentos em perguntas ou respostas.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Answer (score 1):

O único problema é a linha:

```
async def info(ctx, user = discord.Member):
```

O correto seria:

```
async def info(ctx, user: discord.Member):
```

Com essa mudança, você pode passar o argumento 'user' como parâmetro quando utilizar o comando no Discord passando o ID, Tag, Nome de Usuário, etc. (consulte a documentação da biblioteca para ver todas as referências possíveis).

Ex.: dia- info XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Se quiser pegar as informações de quem mandou a mensagem é ainda mais simples:

```
async def info(ctx, user: discord.Member):
   author = ctx.message.author # Salvando o autor da mensagem como variável
   await ctx.send(f"{author.mention}'s id: '{author.id}'") # Mencionando e obtendo o ID do autor da mensagem.
```